# know what columns are created in a tablespace?

Tags: oracle

I have about 50 tables and I would like to know if there is any way to obtain with a query, which columns of my tables are created in a specific tablespace? can you know? or know what things are created in that tablespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might be what you're looking for.

Create a sample table which contains a `CLOB` datatype column:

```
SQL> create table test1
  2  (id     number,
  3   text   clob
  4  );

Table created.
```

`LOB` columns can be stored into a different tablespace than the rest of columns; although I didn't specify storage info (so `TEXT` column resides in the same tablespace as the rest of the columns), querying `USER_LOBS` returns info you're interested in:

```
SQL> select column_name,
  2         table_name,
  3         tablespace_name                 --> this column
  4  from user_lobs
  5  where table_name = 'TEST1';

COLUMN_NAM TABLE_NAME TABLESPACE_NAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
TEXT       TEST1      USERS

SQL>
```

---

Another *free* hint: when you're unsure of where to look for certain things, try to ask the Dictionary. For example:

```
SQL> select * From dictionary where lower(table_name) like '%lob%';

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------
ALL_LOBS                       Description of LOBs contained in tables accessible
                               to the user

ALL_LOB_PARTITIONS
<snip>
USER_LOBS                      Description of the user's own LOBs contained in the
                               user's own tables

<snip>
15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Exactly! It was perfect for me to find the columns I needed, thank you very much! also for giving me the advice of the dictionary;)